# Get network under Network-Manager's management

Tags: debian, networking, networkmanager

Initially, when I had installed Debian 'Wheezy' on my old trusty laptop, it's network was managed by Network-Manager. However, at some point, I think I did something, which lead to the network connectivity, no longer being managed by Network-Manager, though the NM-applet continues to show-up on my GNOME classic desktop.

Question is, how can I get the configuration back to a state where network is again managed by Network-Manager ?

Answer (score 1):

May be you used `/etc/network/interfaces` to configure that interface? This file is managed by legacy `ifupdown` system (and its commands `ifup` and `ifdown`). If `network manager` sees entries for your network interface in `/etc/network/interfaces` it stops handling that interface by itself.

May be you brought the interface down with `ifconfig` - in that case just bring it back up with `sudo ifconfig your_interface_name up`, where you can find the interface name by just running `sudo ifconfig` - it's something like `eth0` or `wlan0`.

See more info in [official page](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html) and [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90778/how-to-bring-up-a-wi-fi-interface-from-a-command-line/90807#90807).

Comment: Hmm... I think might have edited the /etc/network/interfaces. Will try to undo those and see. Thanks for replying.

Comment: @jay No worries. Also, you can find some troubleshooting info in `/var/log/syslog` if get some error messages.