# I have disabled Network Manager in Centos 7 but how to connect with wireless?

Tags: centos, networking, wifi, networkmanager

I have turned off or disabled the NetworkManager service in CentOS 7 but now I want to connect internet through wireless.  So, please tell me how to connect wireless network with Network Manager service disabled?

Answer (score 1):

Enable and configure the `systemd-networkd` service on your system. There is an example [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263826/is-that-possible-for-debian-users-to-connect-to-network-through-systemd-networkd) ; then connect to your wifi using `wpa_supplicant`

Answer (score 0):

Use `ifconfig` to manage to interface from the command line. If you want it to persist between boots then edit `/etc/network/interfaces`.

You can verify if an interface is managed or not using `nmcli dev status`.

When the NetworkManager is disabled all interfaces should be unmanaged. It is also possible to keep NetworkManager running - and then instruct it to only manage specific interfaces.

Apart from bringing the interface up - you probably need wpasupplicant too.

This is all answered in [How to bring up a wi-fi interface from a command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90778/how-to-bring-up-a-wi-fi-interface-from-a-command-line)